# read a file created with fopen php function

Tags: php, joomla, rss, joomla2.5, jwplayer6

I've a problem reading a file created with fopen function, file exsist on the server but can't be accessed and I don't know why, if I download it via ftp it exsist, but I can't acces it from php this is the code for file creation:

```
if (!(file_exists("./media/mod_xml/ $rssname "))) {
$myfile = fopen("./media/mod_xml/ $rssname ", "w+b") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:jwplayer="http://rss.jwpcdn.com/">
';
$txt .='<channel>
';
foreach ($xml->video as $video) {
    $txt .='<item>
    ';
    $txt .='<title>'.$xml->video->titolo.'</title>
    ';
    $txt .='<description>'.$xml->video->descrizione.'</description>
    ';
    $txt .='<jwplayer:image>'.$xml->video->preview.'</jwplayer:image>
    ';
    $txt .='<jwplayer:source file="'.$xml->video->video.'" />
    ';
    $txt .='</item>
    ';
}
$txt .='</channel>
';
$txt .='</rss>
';
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
}
```

this is the code that's trying to read the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("jwplayer<?php echo $xml->video->id;?>").setup({
        playlist: "http://www.example.com/media/mod_xml/<?php echo $xml->video->id;?>.rss",
        width: <?php echo $params->get('vwidth', ''); ?>,
        height: <?php echo $params->get('vheight', ''); ?>
    });
</script>
```

where "mysite.com" is the URL of the site where rss file is located. If I open media/mod_xml/ folder, files are there, and are well formatted, but for some strange reason php doesn't read them.

If I try to point browser to files I get a 404 Not Found error, telling me

The requested URL /media/mod_xml/399.rss was not found on this server.

but the file are there, anyone can help? tnks in advace :)

EDIT:

I load a php file on another server/domain and "convert" it to standard rss for passing it to jwplayer, file is read well and "converted" well:

```
$xmlurl = $params->get('xmlurl', '');
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlurl);
$rssname = $xml->video->id;
$rssname .=".rss";
```

Comment: You have a space in `mod_xml/ $rssname` that could be an issue. It could also be a path issue.

Comment: no, 'cause file exsist and are written on "media/mod_xml" folder, I see them, I download them, if I open them in dreamweaver are well formatted rss :)

Comment: You're using `if (!(file_exists` shouldn't that be `if(file_exists`? You're telling PHP "if file does **not** exist, open the same file". Try `if(file_exists("./media/mod_xml/ $rssname "))`

Comment: I'm telling to php of doing something only if file not exist, but this is not the problem, file exist, if I remove them they are re-created, and are located in "media/mod_xml" folder, file are there and works well.
I use fopn to create a file not to open it, fopen could be used also for creating a file http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: `<?php echo $xml->video->id;?>` won't actually read any file. Where is the code that you're actually using to read the file into the `$xml` variable?

Comment: Can you paste the permissions of the file? Just to make sure you (read: your webpage) can access the file on disk.

Comment: <?php echo $xml->video->id;?> doesn't read the file, it's only outputting the file patch, and it works...

if I use:

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("jwplayer<?php echo $xml->video->id;?>").setup({
        file: "<?php echo $xml->video->video; ?>",
        image: "<?php echo $xml->video->preview; ?>",
        width: <?php echo $params->get('vwidth', ''); ?>,
        height: <?php echo $params->get('vheight', ''); ?>
    });
</script>
file are loaded and displayed, so, isn't a code problem.
I repeat, rss files are stored, but they aren't acccessible by php and/or js code

Comment: Hi LokiSinclair how can I past my file permission? can I attach files here, so you can see permissions? my hosting is a shared hosting so I don't know if permissions showed to me are the same that server stores on the file... Can I impose 777 to the file when I create it via fopen? permission showed me from filezilla are 644, so php and/or JS should read the file

Comment: I founded the error, fope doesn't write a proper rss file, file is created and filled but it isn't a proper RSS file, anyone know how to write a proper RSS file? tnks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Issue. Problem was that files were created but they seem to not be propers RSS files,

I edited the code, and used this code to name file and upload folder:

```
$xmlurl = $params->get('xmlurl', '');
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlurl);
$rssname = $xml->video->id;
$rssname .=".rss";
$upload_dir = "./media/mod_xml/";
if (!(file_exists($upload_dir.$rssname))) {
$myfile = fopen($upload_dir.$rssname, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
...}
```

now files are created as Propers RSS files, and jwPlayer Works Like a charm, tnks anyway...